# Using functions from namespace inside other namespace

Tags: c++

Is it any way to omit outer namespace name for some functions from other namespace inside top-level one?

```
void sample_func();

namespace foo {
void first_func();

namespace bar {
void second_func();
void sample_func();
}
```

Everything is trivial for `first_func()`: just typing `using foo::first_func;` allows to call it just as `fist_func();`

Everything is simple if I want to call `second_func` without any prefix: just `using foo::bar::second_func;` allows to call it as `second_func();`

But is there any way to call it as `bar::second_func();`? It will increase code readability - much better to type and see something like `bar::sample_func` instead of full `foo::bar::sample_func` without names confusion: obviously `using namespace foo::bar` is not an option in that case.

**UPD** I am not interested in importing the whole `foo` or `bar` namespace (i. e. `using namespace ...` directive! I need just some functions from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
namespace bar = foo::bar;
```

to import `foo::bar` into current namespace as just `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Prefix it with the `namespace::` or `::` if not in a namespace i.e

```
::sample_func();

foo::first_func();
bar::second_func();
bar::sample_func();
```

Comment: It requires `using namespace ...`, i. e. every function from global namespace with confused name should be prefixed with `::`. I just need some extensively used functions subset from `foo` and `bar` without exposing all namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
using namespace foo;
```

in any declarative region where you wish to use just `first_func()` and `bar::sample_func()`.

Example:

```
int main()
{
   using namespace foo;
   first_func();
   bar::sample_func();
}
```

Comment: Not the best way: foo can be very very large, I do not want fully import all names from it, just some functions in `foo::bar` namespace, but I need separation between names in `foo::bar` and names in global namespace.